# Pin UITableViewCell's Subview to the top right

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell with an accessory, and I have a UILabel (in this case the word in it is "Rush"). I want to pin that UILabel to the top right of the UITableViewCell. Currently the autolayout contraints are already 0, 0 (top space to superview, trailing space to superview). Ideas?

[image]

Comment: You need to constrain the Leading edge not the trailing edge.

Comment: Why would I pin a constraint to the leading edge? The screen size will change and a constant leading edge won't solve the issue. If I want to pin things on the "right", it'll make more sense to use a trailing edge.

Comment: Think about it from Auto Layout's perspective. It needs to know the button's X, Y, width and height. These can be achieved in a few ways, for your specific example constraining the width, height, top and trailing edge should do it. Since button's are typically a fixed size....you don't need to have a leading edge constraint

Comment: The UITableViewCell content view does NOT fill the entire width of the cell, this is the problem I'm having.